# Anti-alias lines vs markers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, antialiasing

Hi I have a image in MATLAB

[image]

and I want the line to be smooth - look  at the line from 0.4 to 0.8... it's horrible.
When using 'LineSmoothing','on' operator in plot I get this

[image]

I does a good job on lines but it smooths markers also and they are horrible!!

How can I get MATLAB to smooth only lines and not the markers??

Here is the code:

```
clear all;
close all;

bpp = [0.8 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.05];
bpp_j = [0.8 0.4 0.2 0.1];
AAE_JPEG = [1.65 2.91 6.20 10.96];
AAE_JPEG_2000 = [1.39 2.29 3.78 6.75 12.52];
AAE_EEDC = [2.08 2.67 3.80 5.94 9.31];
hold on;
plot(bpp_j, AAE_JPEG, 'k','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',9,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineSmoothing','on');
plot(bpp, AAE_JPEG_2000, 'k', 'LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineSmoothing','on');
plot(bpp, AAE_EEDC, 'k', 'LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineSmoothing','on');

plot(bpp_j, AAE_JPEG, 'x','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',8,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
plot(bpp, AAE_JPEG_2000, 'o', 'LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
plot(bpp, AAE_EEDC, 'v', 'LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');

LL = plot(rand(1,2),rand(1,2),'k-x','visible','off','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',8);
LK = plot(rand(1,2),rand(1,2),'k-o','visible','off','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6);
LI = plot(rand(1,2),rand(1,2),'k-v','visible','off','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',6);
legend([LL,LK, LI],'JPEG','JPEG 2000','EEDC')


axis([0 0.9 0 14])
xlabel('bpp');
ylabel('AAE');
grid on;
```

and while I'm still here... how can I only display 0.05 0.1 0.2 0.4 and 0.8 on x-axis?

Comment: I don't see how your code smooths markers. I think it only smooths the lines in the first three plot lines. The plot lines where you plot the markers (the second three) do not have their LineSmoothing properties set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just try using [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) without even `linesmoothing` the lines...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a MATLAB here so I can't test but does it work if you plot the smoothed lines without markers

```
plot(bpp_j, AAE_JPEG, 'k','LineWidth',1.5,'LineSmoothing','on');
```

then another plot of the markers with no lines?

```
plot(bpp_j, AAE_JPEG, 'x','MarkerSize',8,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
```

As for the x-axis ticks see [matlab x axis label set as a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248676/matlab-x-axis-label-set-as-a-vector)

Comment: because it still smoothed the markers in the second command or because I didn't get the syntax right? Try swapping the lines around so it draws the markers first and the smoothed lines second. Also try each one separately to make sure I got the syntax right - it might be that the first one draws markers anyway and you have to explicitly tell it not to : )

Comment: I tired switching order, deactivateing smooth where matlab plots markers and always smoothes all the picture. Export_fig from the answer above works great!!