# smoothing graph line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, smoothing, loess

I have the following graph and i would like to make it more pleasing to the eyes by smoothing the graph. is it possible ?

[image]

```
tempyr = 1880:1:2014;  
temperature = temp(1:2, 1:135);
Tempval = {'Annual Mean','5 Year Mean'}
TH = zeros(size(Tempval));
hold on
TH = plot( tempyr', temperature', '-o', 'Marker', '.');
xlabel( 'year', 'fontsize', 24); ylabel( 'Temperature Anomaly (Degree Cel)', 'fontsize', 24 );
legend(TH, Tempval)
grid on
```

Ideal graph. 
[image]

Comment: Which graph would you like to smooth? The annual mean? The 5-year mean? Can you provide an example of how you envision the result of such smoothing? How would you address the loss of data?

Comment: How is the *ideal* graph different from the graph you produce?

Comment: Do you maybe want the lines not to have stairs? Like antialiasing?

Comment: @Mathias yeap. I would like to remove the sharp drop or increase in height. (stairs) would that be possible ? Also how do i incorporate such function into my code ?

Comment: If you have the curve fitting toolbox, you can use the `smooth()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TH = plot( tempyr', temperature', '-o', 'Marker', '.','LineSmoothing','on');
```

and also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456460/anti-alias-lines-vs-markers-in-matlab), especially the [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) reference might prove useful.